# Remove an action added within a class in a WordPress plugin

Tags: actions, oop

I'm trying to replace a function in a WordPress plugin (Easy property listing) without success at the moment.

The action is added like that, in a class :

```
<?php
/**
 * Search Object
 *
 * @package     EPL
 * @subpackage  Classes/Search
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2016, Merv Barrett
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.php GNU Public License
 * @since       3.0
 */
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
/**
 * EPL_Search_Fields Class
 *
 * @since      3.0
 * @author     Taher Atashbar <taher.atashbar@gmail.com>
 */
class EPL_Search_Fields {
    /**
     * Initialize hooks.
     *
     * @since  3.0
     * @return void
     */
    public function init() {
        // Initialize hooks for displaying search frontend fields.
        add_action( 'epl_frontend_search_field_text', array( $this, 'render_text' ), 10, 5 );
        add_action( 'epl_frontend_search_field_checkbox', array( $this, 'render_checkbox' ), 10, 5 );
        add_action( 'epl_frontend_search_field_select', array( $this, 'render_select' ), 10, 5 );
        add_action( 'epl_frontend_search_field_multiple_select', array( $this, 'render_multiple_select' ), 10, 5 );
        add_action( 'epl_frontend_search_field_number', array( $this, 'render_number' ), 10, 5 );
        add_action( 'epl_frontend_search_field_hidden', array( $this, 'render_hidden' ), 10, 5 );
        add_action( 'epl_frontend_search_field_radio', array( $this, 'render_radio' ), 10, 5 );
        add_action( 'epl_frontend_search_field_checkbox_multiple', array( $this, 'render_checkbox_multiple' ), 10, 5 );
    }
```

[View the file on Github](https://github.com/easypropertylistings/Easy-Property-Listings/blob/315c18215494b50b148ce7d843ff05be096e8ea0/lib/includes/class-epl-search-fields.php)

The function I tried to replace is render_select.
Further down in the file :

```
/**
     * Renders search frontend Select field.
     *
     * @since  3.0
     * @param  array  $field
     * @param  string $config
     * @param  string $value
     * @param  string $post_type
     * @param  string $property_status
     * @return void
     */
    public function render_select( array $field, $config = '', $value = '', $post_type = '', $property_status = '' ) {
        if ( isset( $field['wrap_start'] ) ) {
            echo '<div class="' . $field['wrap_start'] . '">';
        }
        ?>
        <div class="epl-search-row epl-search-row-select epl-<?php echo $field['meta_key']; ?> fm-block <?php echo isset( $field['class'] ) ? $field['class'] : ''; ?>">
            <label for="<?php echo $field['meta_key']; ?>" class="epl-search-label fm-label">
                <?php echo apply_filters( 'epl_search_widget_label_' . $field['meta_key'], $field['label'] ); ?>
            </label>
            <div class="field">
                <select
                    name="<?php echo $field['meta_key']; ?>"
                    id="<?php echo $field['meta_key']; ?>"
                    class="in-field field-width">
                    <option value="">
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'epl_search_widget_option_label_' . $field['option_filter'], __( 'Any', 'easy-property-listings'  ) ); ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php
                    if ( isset( $field['options'] ) && ! empty( $field['options'] ) ) {
                        foreach ( $field['options'] as $k => $v ) {
                            echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $k ) . '"' . selected( $k, $value, false ) . '>' . $v . '</option>';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        if ( isset( $field['wrap_end'] ) ) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to remove the first option value in a select input in my search bar :

```
<option value="">
    <?php echo apply_filters( 'epl_search_widget_option_label_' . $field['option_filter'], __( 'Any', 'easy-property-listings'  ) ); ?>
</option>
```

So I just copied this render_select function without the "option" in a plugin, and I named it "render_select2" and it's working. I doubled my select input without the first option value.

Now i try to remove the initial action. I tried a lot of code (on this forum and in some post on Google) without success.

In my functions.php :

```
function remove_searchfield() {

    $class = 'EPL_Search_Fields'; // Name of class the method was built in.
    $tag = 'epl_frontend_search_field_select'; // the name of the hook
    $function = 'render_select'; // the function you wish to remove
    $priority = 10; // must be an integer

    global $class;
    remove_action ( $tag, array( $class, $function ), $priority);
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_searchfield');
```

Do you guys have an idea how to do that? My PhP knowledge is limited and I'm going crazy ;).

Any tips any advice would be welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on how `EPL_Search_Fields` is instantiated. `render_select()` isn't static, so you need to pass the existing instance of `EPL_Search_Fields` to `remove_action()` to be able to remove it.

Comment: Thank you Jacob, I'm not sure how to do that, I find an occurence of the class in an other file :
[Github](https://github.com/easypropertylistings/Easy-Property-Listings/blob/11e7a6eab73af2d43cf6d3f6e7c6d8384f421c37/easy-property-listings.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work :

```
function remove_searchfield() {

    $tag = 'epl_frontend_search_field_select'; // the name of the hook
    $function = 'render_select'; // the function you wish to remove
    $priority = 10; // must be an integer

    remove_action ( $tag, array( Easy_Property_Listings::instance()->search_fields, $function ), $priority);
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_searchfield');
```

Thanks Jacob for the help ;)